# How can I get python to print the output of this program in an HTML file?

Tags: python, html, browser

The program below scrapes the text of a web page. How could I get `print(output)` to display in an HTML file so it could be loaded in a web browser?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = ''
res = requests.get(url)
html_page = res.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, 'html.parser')
text = soup.find_all(text=True)

output = ''
blacklist = [
    '[document]',
    'noscript',
    'header',
    'html',
    'meta',
    'head', 

]

for t in text:
    if t.parent.name not in blacklist:
        output += '{} '.format(t)

print(output)
```

Comment: The question is how you want to display the text in html file?
In `<pre>` tag??
Also post sample of what `print(output)` is displaying.

Comment: Are you asking how to write to a file?

Comment: Read about [pandas.to_html](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html)

Answer (score 0):

- Assume you want to display whatever store in `output` variable in HTML as `<pre>`.
- You can write this text to `HTML` file between `<pre>` and `<\pre>`.

```py
with open('display.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write("<pre>\n")
    for line in output.split("\n"):
        f.write(line)
        f.write("\n")
    f.write("<\\pre>")
```

- now this will generate a file called `display.html` which will display all the text in output variable to web.